# Bootstrap: Factors affecting erosion

Tags: r, glm, statistics-bootstrap

I have a problem deriving a meaningful generalized linear regression model. The predictor variable depends on several predictands of which some are factors, and other vectors (elevation, slope, depth to permafrost (vector), exposure (rank, vector), permeability (factor)). There are seven groups of the data which correspond to their geographic location. The predictands within these groups are always equal, so that only the predicted variable (erosion rate) changes. There are 1700 data points.
I would like to set up a generalized linear regression model to test the influence of the predictands on the erosion rate. As the data are spatially autocorrelated, the analysis should take 30 samples from each group, then run the glm, let's say 10,000 times. I would like to compare the spread of the coefficients. Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: I solved this problem ultimately like this:

#how many loops
B<-1025

#tpercentage of samples used to create dataset for analysis
C<-1
#how many samples, as percentage of total transects within reach
cr1<-358
cr2<-240
cr3<-164
cr4<-47
cr5<-58
cr6<-101
cr7<-57
#matrices for coefficients and p-values
st.intercept<-matrix(NA,B,4)
st.ice<-matrix(NA,B,4)
st.slope<-matrix(NA,B,4)
st.elevation<-matrix(NA,B,4)
st.exposure<-matrix(NA,B,4)
st.perm.depth<-matrix(NA,B,4)
st.permeability<-matrix(NA,B,4)
st.aic<-matrix(NA,B,1)

Comment: and then:
#GLM loop
for (b in  1:B)
{
#resample from dataset
CR1<-Dataset[Dataset$Reach == "CR1",][sample(nrow(Dataset[Dataset$Reach == "CR1",]),C*cr1, replace=TRUE),]
CR2<-Dataset[Dataset$Reach == "CR2",][sample(nrow(Dataset[Dataset$Reach == "CR2",]),C*cr2,replace=TRUE),]
CR3<-Dataset[Dataset$Reach == "CR3",][sample(nrow(Dataset[Dataset$Reach == "CR3",]),C*cr3, replace=TRUE),]
CR4<-Dataset[Dataset$Reach == "CR4",][sample(nrow(Dataset[Dataset$Reach == "CR4",]),C*cr4, replace=TRUE),]

Comment: CR5<-Dataset[Dataset$Reach == "CR5",][sample(nrow(Dataset[Dataset$Reach == "CR5",]),C*cr5, replace=TRUE),]
CR6<-Dataset[Dataset$Reach == "CR6",][sample(nrow(Dataset[Dataset$Reach == "CR6",]),C*cr6, replace=TRUE),]
CR7<-Dataset[Dataset$Reach == "CR7",][sample(nrow(Dataset[Dataset$Reach == "CR7",]),C*cr7, replace=TRUE),]

#merge all subsets
condsubset<-rbind(CR1, CR2, CR3, CR4, CR5, CR6, CR7)

#the function
GLM<-glm(formula = Erosion ~ Ice + Exposure + Elev + Slope + PermafrostDepth + Permeability, family = gaussian(identity), 
    data = condsubset)

Comment: #populate coefficients in data frames
st.intercept[b,]<-coef(summary(GLM))[1,]
st.ice[b,]<-coef(summary(GLM))[2,]
st.exposure[b,]<-coef(summary(GLM))[3,]
st.elevation[b,]<-coef(summary(GLM))[4,]
st.slope[b,]<-coef(summary(GLM))[5,]
st.perm.depth[b,]<-coef(summary(GLM))[6,]
st.permeability[b,]<-coef(summary(GLM))[7,]
st.aic[b,] <- GLM$aic
}